# Why are foreign keys active after disabling triggers on a table?

Tags: postgresql, triggers, foreign-keys, truncate

I'm trying to refresh some data that's referred to by other data - I want to truncate and reload the ms_automobile table, but the rm_automobile table has a foreign key to it.

It looks like the 'DISABLE TRIGGER' statements are working (run as postgres, a superuser):

```
mobilesurvey=# ALTER TABLE ms_automobile DISABLE TRIGGER ALL;
ALTER TABLE
mobilesurvey=# ALTER TABLE rm_automobile DISABLE TRIGGER ALL;
ALTER TABLE
```

But I can't then truncate the ms_automobile table:

```
mobilesurvey=# TRUNCATE TABLE ms_automobile;
ERROR:  cannot truncate a table referenced in a foreign key constraint
DETAIL:  Table "rm_automobile" references "ms_automobile".
HINT:  Truncate table "rm_automobile" at the same time, or use TRUNCATE ... CASCADE.
```

Again, I do not want to lose the rm_automobile data; after the TRUNCATE I'm planning on doing a pg_restore that includes the missing ms_automobile data.

If possible, I'd like to disable instead of dropping the constraints - there are more of them, and maintaining disable/enable seems a lot less error-prone than maintaining drop/add.

So, how can I actually disable the foreign keys here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disabling triggers works as you expect on DELETE (and not on TRUNCATE).

```
DELETE FROM ms_automobile;
```

TRUNCATE is implemented in the specific way different from INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE. It doesn't use triggers but checks referential integrity once before its execution.